# Spark sql using posix

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

To find non numeric rows we can do something like below in sparksql

```
spark.sql("select * from tabl where UPC rlike '[^0-9]'").show()
```

can this same query also be written like below? I tested it does not seem to work, basically I am trying to use :alpha:/:digit:/:alnum: posix commands

```
spark.sql("select * from tabl where UPC rlike '[^[:digit:]]'").show()
```

```
spark-sql> select * from ( select '8787687' col1) where rlike (col1,'^[[:digit:]]+$');
Time taken: 0.02 seconds
spark-sql>
```